# Xcode 6.0.1 Organizer crash on while submitting app to app store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode6

Since evening i was trying to submit new version of app to app store. I click on Archive. My xcode organizer get opened up.

I click on Submit button , Choose the developer profile from account and when i press NEXT button , Xcode crashes in few seconds.

I have done all hit and trail :

1) Xcode restart , system restart

2) Creation of new distribution profile .

Still its crashing.

Apple crash log.

```
Process:         Xcode [2104]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         6.0.1 (6528)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6528000000000000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [181]
Responsible:     Xcode [2104]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-26 21:10:42.110 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  14C17270-F41D-A2A7-9D0D-566B5D6B5FF2

Sleep/Wake UUID: B75584F8-AADD-444A-9B65-4E0B10627FC5

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A317
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-6528/IDEFoundation/Distribution/IDEDistributionProvisioning.m:34
Details:  Assertion failed: [rootDistributionItems count] > 0
Object:   <IDEDistributionProvisioning: 0x7feeba6e3bd0>
Method:   -initWithRootDistributionItems:distributionMethod:teamID:codesignableDevicesOrNil:logging:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7feeb04173d0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
```

Comment: You have validated it before you submitted it? Did that work ok?

Comment: Yeah on click of validation also its getting crashed. I tried all , validate , export and submit

Comment: Does it happen I your other projects? I know it's a bit extreme but maybe download a new copy of Xcode and reinstall it

Comment: I have new copy today xcode 6.0.1 latest version.Its happening to all projects.

Comment: sounds like its an xcode thing then not your project otherwise it wouldn't happen on all of them, try a fresh download and reinstall? maybe a none beta version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem Resolved:

1) Removed provision profile.

2) Created new provision profile with new name

3) Click on organizer , click on submit.

4) Click on accounts tab , click on the developer profile , click on view details. Click on refresh button to get all newly created profiles

5) Click done . and app submitted to store successfully.

NO CRASH.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Login into developer.apple.com -> Member Center
2. See if you have yet agreed to any latest iOS Developer Program License Agreement.
3. You need to agree with all the agreements first.
4. After agreed, try submitting your app again.

This is how I resolved my case, I have to agreed to the latest iOS Developer Program License Agreement.

Answer (score 1):

I had to re-download Xcode 5.1.1 from the member center. This worked without any problems.